# Cut, Copy, Paste keyboard shortcut problem on Ubuntu Desktop 20.04

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, 20.04, gnome-shell, desktop-icons

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 on my desktop and when I tried to use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd>,<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>, <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> shortcuts to cut/copy/paste a file/text/folder etc. nothing happened. I have searched all of the related answered questions and videos but none of them applied to me. Any suggestions?

Comment: Desktop functionality is limited in Ubuntu because they introduced new technology for that.